# Number of n-permutations with repetition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $a_n(k)$ be number of n-permutations with repetition on set $\{1,\dots,k\}$ in which $k$ occurs odd numbers of times. I have to find formula of $a_n(k)$ for $k > 1$. Let $b_n(k)$ be number of n-permutations with repetition on set $\{1,\dots,k\}$ in which $k$ occurs even numbers of times. $a_n(k) = b_n(k-1) + a_n(k-1)(k-1)$ (on the last position we can place k and b_n(k-1) times numbers on other places or we can place place non-k [$k-1$] on the last position and $a_n(k-1)$ times numbers on other places). Similarly, $b_n(k) = a_n(k-1) + b_n(k-1)(k-1)$. Moreover, $a_1(k) = 1$ and $b_1(k) = 0$. What to do next?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to count, there are a number of errors in the question. The recurrences should be $a_n(k)=b_{n-1}(k)+a_{n-1}(k)(k-1)$ and $b_n(k)=a_{n-1}(k)+b_{n-1}(k)(k-1)$, and the initial values for $b$ should be $b_1(k)=k-1$ (as zero is an even number). You can reduce the recurrences to a single sequence by using $a_n(k)+b_n(k)=k^n$.

But I think it's actually easier to count directly than to solve the recurrences. For $b_n$, we can choose an even number $j$ of the $n$ places in which $k$ occurs and then choose the remaining elements in $(k-1)^{n-j}$ ways. Thus

\begin{align}
b_n(k)&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(k-1)^{n-j}\mathbf1_{2\mid j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(k-1)^{n-j}\frac12\left(1+(-1)^j\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(k-1)^{n-j}1^j+\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj(k-1)^{n-j}(-1)^j\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(k^n+(k-2)^n\right)\;.
\end{align}

Likewise,

$$
a_n=\frac12\left(k^n-(k-2)^n\right)\;.
$$